# Linprog can solve a LP primal but not dual?

Tags: python, optimization, scipy

I am able to solve the following minimization problem with scipy linprog with the matrix A_ub:

```
A_ub = [[ 1 10  0  3]
        [ 6  2  3  6]
        [ 3  5  4  2]
        [ 4  9  2  2]]
```

and

```
b_ub = [1,1,1,1]
```

and the minimization problem is `c = [-1,-1,-1,-1]` (i.e negative of norm 1).
Calling the linprog from scipy gives the following result (as expected):

```
scipy.optimize.linprog(c, A_ub=A_ub, b_ub=b_ub)

    con: array([], dtype=float64)
     fun: -0.2777777777777778
 message: 'Optimization terminated successfully.'
     nit: 7
   slack: array([0.83333333, 0.        , 0.        , 0.44444444])
  status: 0
 success: True
       x: array([0.        , 0.        , 0.22222222, 0.05555556])
```

However, I also need to find the solution for the dual of the problem.

From my understanding of the minimax theorem, the above problem is equivalent to:

```
scipy.optimize.linprog(-b_ub, A_ub=A_ub.T, b_ub=c)
```

However, running such command would result in errors:

```
     con: array([], dtype=float64)
     fun: 0.0
 message: "Phase 1 of the simplex method failed to find a feasible solution. The pseudo-objective function evaluates to 4.0e+00 which exceeds the required tolerance of 1e-12 for a solution to be considered 'close enough' to zero to be a basic solution. Consider increasing the tolerance to be greater than 4.0e+00. If this tolerance is unacceptably  large the problem may be infeasible."
     nit: 0
   slack: array([-1., -1., -1., -1.])
  status: 2
 success: False
   x: array([0., 0., 0., 0.])
```

If I increase the tolerance to a large value (10) then it does terminate with a solution but I don't think it is correct as the function value is not the same as the primal value.
I really appreciate any help and hint regarding this problem and how to find the solution to the dual.

best,
Hieu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a mistake in calling linprog,

the dual of the problem should be :

```
minimizing b_ub
s.t
-A_transpose *x <= c
```

Thus, the linprog call would work if I use:

```
linprog(b_ub, -A_transpose, c)
```